# How can I make Mac Finder show the actual size of files not 'size on disk' multiples of 4KB

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, finder

I understand that the minimum disk allocation block is 4kb, but in Finder I don't really care about that. I'd much rather be able to see which of 12 similar text files/images is largest, expecially because I do web work and it's very useful to see the actual size of your files without having to 'get info' on all of them.

There's no simple option I can see, but if there's a terminal command or file somewhere I can edit, I'd love to be able to.

I'm using Snow Leopard 10.6.5, btw. :)

Comment: Odd: above 20 kB not everything is a multiple of 4 kB on my Mac, but indeed even 1 byte files show as 4 kB.

Comment: Using the inspector instead of Get Info (Cmd-Opt-I instead of Cmd-I) might be less painful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open AppleScript Editor, paste this:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set selection_list to selection as list

    set item_list to ""
    repeat with idx from 1 to count selection_list
        set item_list to item_list & name of item idx of selection_list & " - " & size of item idx of selection_list & " bytes
"
    end repeat
    display dialog item_list buttons {"OK"} default button 1
end tell
```

Save as application somewhere and drag it it to your Finder toolbar. Whenever you click on it, a dialog informs you of the size of the items selected in your frontmost Finder window.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: That is a much better alternative than Get Info! I still would love to find a way to make finder actually show the amount (I generally browse in details view).. but that might be too much to ask.

Comment: @Damon I think there is no alternative. I looked. Therefore the scripting solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since we can't fix it, a good option would be getting an [alternative to Finder](https://superuser.com/questions/29268/alternative-file-managers-on-mac-os-x). I suggest [ForkLift](http://www.binarynights.com/forklift).
[image]